# How to determine if auto negotiation with switch is finished

Tags: ubuntu, networking, cisco, switch

When I connect ubuntu network interface to cisco switch, the ports of switch and ubuntu starts auto negotiation.

I need to know if auto negotiation is finished or not.

The easy way is ping & wait until the replies come but I need to know when exactly the auto negotiation is finished.

I searched around but I could not find any way.

Is there a way to determine that? Foe example some file in proc or some thing like that.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't [unix@SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) a better place for this?

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is like this: dmeg says the negotiation is complete but the switch is not ready and the led of the port on the switch is still red and it get a while for it to get green.

Your problem seems to be that the switchport isn't configured as a spanning tree edge port.   Edge ports are optimized to forward to quickly; otherwise the switch port goes through a longer cycle of spanning tree states.

Ask the switch admin to configure "spanning-tree portfast" on this port.

Answer (score 0):

Something like ethtool will show you the settings and negotiation state for your interface. Looking at how they get that information might give you a neater solution than just running ethtool in a loop.

Another option would be looking at /var/log/messages - kernel logs there when negotiation complete.

Comment: The problem is like this: dmeg says the negotiation is complete but the switch is not ready and the led of the port on the switch is still red and it get a while for it to get green.

Comment: Is that not more likely to be a spanning tree issue? You might want to investigate portfast options. I come at this from the server side so don't take me as definitive on network config issues. Mike Pennington's answer covers this in more detail.